# subdomain redirect to same backend in haproxy

Tags: linux, load-balancing, acl, haproxy

how can i configure host path redirection of all sub domains to a same backed server.

For example

```
my domain is example.com 
sub domains are *.example.com
I need to redirect *.example.com/abc/ to  another backed server.
```

My frontend ACLs are

```
acl host_star hdr(host) -i *.example.com
use_backend back_live if host_star

acl is_node path_beg -i /abc/
use_backend backend_node if host_star is_node
```

I need to go abc.example.com/abc/ and xyz.example.com/abc/ to same backend server

Answer (score 0):

I completed it by using hdr_end(host)

> acl host_star hdr_end(host) -i .example.com